# Angular Ts update an element in for loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My question is that how can I update my html DOM element value that is binded from a ts file in every step of for loop not at the end of the loop ?
I want to see  all values while the loop is executing.

Suppose that I have a html document like that:

```
<p> progress is = {{progress}} </p>
<input type="file" style="align-content:center" (change)="incomingfile($event)">
```

And I have a Ts file like that:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css']
})
export class Foo implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  display="none";


     arrayBuffer:any;
  file:File;
  progress="0";

     updateProgress(i,data){
    this.progress = (100*i/data.length).toString();
    return 1
  }

incomingfile(event) 
    {

      document.getElementById("uploadButton").setAttribute("disabled","true");
    this.file= event.target.files[0]; 
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
        var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);

        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i){
          this.updateProgress(i,data);
         arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);

        }



      }

      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
      this.display="block";
      document.getElementById("uploadButton").removeAttribute("disabled");

    }
```

on button click I want to see the output from browser like that: progress is = 0 (when in for loop i = 0 ) progress is = 10 (when in for loop i = 1 ) progress is = 20 (when in for loop i = 2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround by simulating a fake setTimeout because all of this happen in the front-end side so there might be no time at all. but you can make the progress bar pattern when you upload it to a backend so you will have a progress from the backend and you can display it.
Follow this tutorial for uploading file to the server : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y

Also don't use document.getElementById inside angular components best practice is to use the native element inside the component or make a ref in input field and reference it inside the component.
For the technique you use it's preferable to use a boolean variable that controls this behavior and use [disabled] in the input field.

I made this stackblitz that explain it well with the other element ref technique: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zphhej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts